Would it be possible today, in practice, to launch through the eye of a hurricane as portrayed in the 1969 space movie, "Marooned"?
I think that "launch" should mean here to launch the kind of orbital class mission that could send supplies to a space station or (in the case of the movie) rescue some stranded astronauts.
It would make an epic photo!

Some things to consider:

The rocket will probably need to be secured within a hurricane-proof building until the eye reaches the launch site.
It will take some time to get the rocket from that building to the pad, fuel it, and launch it.
Let's assume that it will take 10 hours for this eye to pass over the launch site.


[+1] Here's some less "epic" scenes from ISS 1. 2, 3 I think there's a Soyuz reentry seen from ISS post also, but I can't find it right now.

Weather in part of the downrange abort zone for a crewed launch would likely be out of limits, to put it mildly. So probably uncrewed launches only. Unless you have Gregory Peck running things that is.

FYI, an eye taking 10 hours to pass over is wholly implausible. In fact, entire hurricanes generally take less than 10 hours to pass over a fixed point. Ten minutes is roughly what you'll have for the eye.

Aren't hurricane wind speeds rather trivial [150Mph] compared to the forces a rocket normally experiences?  Airplanes fly into them for research.

I think at ground level the winds would pick up debris that would probably damage a rocket out on the pad. But that's just my assumption - feel free to challenge it.

@GregMiller they’re entirely different loading regimes. Rockets are built to withstand a lot of vertical force but a lot less horizontal. Obviously they’re not entirely flimsy horizontally, but the SLS for example is rated for 137 kph winds. Phil’s point about debris is also pertinent

STS-115 (Atlantis) in September 2006 was being rolled back to the VAB from pad 39B because a passing hurricane was forecast to cause winds speeds at the pad greater than 202 km/h which was the maximum allowed for a Shuttle sitting outdoors. However during the several hour long trip back to the VAB the weather forecast improved, so they stopped the rollback and brought Atlantis back to pad 39B. It launched a few days later. The only Shuttle to ever do a (figurative) U-turn on the crawlerway.

@fyrepenguin Indeed. Just how much can tall skinny rockets bend? (roughly, safely) and Most noodle-like (highest aspect ratio) orbital launch vehicle ever? and If not constrained by underpasses, etc., would Falcon 9 have been less of a flying noodle?

@fyrepenguin Rockets don't just go straight up though, the force of a moderate turn under several G's of thrust likely dwarf that of hurricane winds.  And there's plenty of failed launches where you see the rocket go side on to the wind, thrusters still firing without breaking up.  The wind damage for launch probably has a lot more to do with the launch platform than the rocket.  The 137 km/s in the story you linked was not the maximum rating, but the max official recorded wind during that specific storm, it reports unofficial records of 160km and it sounds like the damage was pretty trivial.

@phil1008 I wouldn't say there's no chance of hitting a tree on the way up, but debris in a hurricane is pretty spread out due to the fact that the winds increase slowly over several days.  This is why you can see idiots standing in crazy winds without much fear of getting hit by something.  See the story fyrepenguin linked, there was no serious damage from debris.

@GregMiller no, they measured a maximum of 132 on the tower. ”Free said that, while at the pad, the vehicle experienced peak wind gusts of 132 kilometers per hour at the 18-meter level at the pad, just under the vehicle’s rated limit of 137 kilometers per hour“. Perhaps it has a higher in-flight off-axis g-loading rating higher than that, but that’s what they specified here. The higher winds also are at higher altitudes, likely higher than the vehicle

@fyrepenguin Thanks, I misread that part, but I believe the conclusions I made still stand.

update: It seems I can only address the "possible to launch" part, but not the "possible to fuel first" or "possible to move over a big hole for the exhaust first" part.

Yes, with the operative word being "possible".
I have some first-hand experience, with the eye of a typhoon passing pretty-much overhead (that's what hurricanes are called here). The wind stopped, period. I could open my windows, it was quite calm. Unfortunately, even though it was night, I didn't see starts because I was too scared to leave my apartment, but certainly there is enough photographic evidence on the internet that the sky is clear. They fly planes in eyes.
Wikipedia's Eye (cyclone) confirms what we can guess, that the rotation and wind go to near zero in the center.
It also confirms that the eye gets wider as you go higher, better allowing for a curved trajectory that might not be the same direction that the system is moving.
There are plenty of risks, it's not guaranteed, but it is certainly possible.

 
Sources Maysak seen from the ISS 3. and  File:Fly00449 - Flickr - NOAA Photo Library.jpg
 
Sources: Reddit Awesome view of the hurricane's eye from the ground (Photo Credit Jim Edds) and Eye of Hurricane Michael, just west of Mexico Beach, FL 10/10/2018

I like that you had firsthand experience! I'm also wondering if it's possible to get the rocket out of whatever hurricane-proof building that its prepped in, out onto the launch pad, and fueled up in the time that hurricane's eye passes over. I probably should have been clearer about that in the question.

@phil1008 well why don't you go back and update your question because that's a pretty important consideration. I'll keep an "eye" on it and edit this answer accordingly :-) One DOES have to get fuel into a rocket to launch it and that would be pretty hard to bring to the rocket. One doesn't have to worry about destroying the launch site if it's an emergency (I didn't see the movie so lack context) but fueling seems to be a serious challenge. It all sounds really really unlikely, unless the hurricane stops moving (which they do do occasionally)

It takes only 3.5 hours to fuel Ariane 6 and it is already conveniently standing over the big hole (they move the building rather than the rocket).

@phil1008 as I recall, they left Artemis 1 out on the pad during a hurricane, though I don’t think it was a direct hit

@ScienceSnake no, they considered rolling it back but they were also worried about wear and tear from the vibration/etc of the transport, so they left it out. https://spacenews.com/nasa-investigating-very-minor-artemis-hurricane-damage/

”Free said that, while at the pad, the vehicle experienced peak wind gusts of 132 kilometers per hour at the 18-meter level at the pad, just under the vehicle’s rated limit of 137 kilometers per hour. However, other sensors at the pad reported gusts as high as 160 kilometers per hour at higher levels. NASA has not disclosed any certifications for wind speeds at higher levels, or the significance of the 18-meter level.”

fyrepenguin - From a news website, "According to the National Hurricane Center, the difference in the wind speed hitting the 30th floor of tall buildings averages 20 mph faster than the wind speeds on the first floor." Probably 18 meters is just where they have one of their sensors, and they were just pointing out that while it was below the limit at 18 meters, wind speed exceeded the limit higher up on the tower. I'm guessing they don't actually have different limits for different levels on the tower, it's probably 137 km/h at any level..

I wonder if for SLS they have the ability to rotate the mobile launch platform to keep the rocket on the leeward side of the tower.

Agreed, @StevePemberton, I was just quoting the specifics from the article. I believe the “160 at higher levels” may refer to heights above the launch tower, so it’s unclear whether any part of the stack exceeded 137 kph limit or not.

@phil1008 that might be an interesting follow-on question. It’s not evident to me that they have that capability, but a quick search didn’t fully preclude the possibility

@phil1008 - the SLS mobile launch platform, originally built for Constellation, was based on the MLPs used for Apollo and Shuttle. It does not have the capability to rotate. The MLP is lifted by one of the tracked vehicle Crawler-Transporters used during Apollo/Shuttle, which carries the MLP to the launch pad. The CT then retreats to a safe location for launch. The CTs can steer, so in theory they could maneuver the stack into a different orientation, but there isn't really room to do that type of maneuver since it rolls on a prebuilt track of crushed rock.

@phil1008 It's at least 5 hours from the VAB to the pad on the crawler-transporter.

@phil1008, fueling time wouldn't be an issue for an all-solid-fuel rocket.

@Mark True, but most orbital-class rockets make use of liquid-fueled stages.

@phil1008 luckily the question specifies "possible', not "probable". There have been some "odd ducks", e.g. Why does PSLV use four stages to get to LEO, and why do they alternate solid, liquid, solid, liquid? The first stage is "one of the largest solid rocket boosters in the world" and the two liquid stages don't seem to be cryogenic - I wonder if the PSLV would be one of the best candidates for quick fueling at least (not sure how fast to move it over a big hole)

Can I launch from a boomer? Will make getting into position so much easier.
